# How to create custom RColorBrewer palette?

Tags: r, colors

I want to change the color scale based on a hex code color I provide.

For example below the `color_scale` argument takes a value based on available color palette from `RColorBrewer` library

```
library(bupaR)
patients %>%
    process_map(type = frequency("relative_case", color_scale = "Purples"))
```

[image]

Is there any way that I can create a custom palette which is not part of the RColorBrewer palette (`RColorBrewer::brewer.pal.info`) so that it can be an input to the `process_map` `color_scale` argument?

For example, I want the color scale to be generated based on this hexcode `#004b88`.

If I simply replace the hexcode as below, I would get the following error which suggests that I'm only bounded by whatever color palettes provided by RColorBrewer which I think shouldn't be the case

```
> patients %>%
+     process_map(type = frequency("relative_case", color_scale = "#004b88"))
Error: `colorize_node_attrs()` REASON:
* The color palette is not an `RColorBrewer` or `viridis` palette`()` REASON:
* The color palette is not an `RColorBrewer` or `viridis` palette`()` REASON:
* The color palette is not an `RColorBrewer` or `viridis` palette
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit

I just read your question properly - I do not believe there is a way to use a non-RColorBrewer palette with the process_map() function. A potential workaround is to find the source code and create your own function based on the bupaR function to accept other palettes, but as far as I can tell it will only accept RColorBrewer or Viridis palettes at present.

--

Depending on your use case you could use `colorRampPalette()` to build your palette from white to #004b88, e.g.

To see "Purples":

```
library(RColorBrewer)
scales::show_col(brewer.pal(6, name = "Purples"))
```

[image: example_1.png]

To create and see a new palette:

```
palette_blues <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("white", "#004b88"))(6)
scales::show_col(palette_blues)
```

[image: example_2.png]

And if you want more than 6 colours or you don't want to start with white you can change the number and 'drop' some from the end, e.g.

```
palette_blues <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("white", "#004b88"))(12)
scales::show_col(palette_blues[4:12])
```

[image: example_3.png]